# client-side routing with grapnel.js not working

Tags: routes, client-side

Has any one used this router library grapnel.js for client-side routing?
I am following this [tutorial](https://github.com/baseprime/grapnel#stopping-a-route-event) from their github page.

This is my code:

```
var router = new Grapnel({ pushState: true })
router.get("/products", function(req){
   //...my handler
})
```

When I enter "/products" in the url address bar, my handler is not called.

In most of the other client-side routing libraries, after having setup your routes, then you call a method like `.start()` or `.init()` to actually start the router (e.g see [page.js](https://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/)).

Is there a similar start method to start a grapnel router? or am I forgetting something. Thank you community.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
Grapnel.listen();
```

At it at the end of your code.